# What are the basic qualifications to become a cricket coach?

Tags: cricket, coaching

All the international cricket coaches, I know, now are ex-cricket players.

Is it necessary to have experience in playing international matches to become a cricket coach?
I need to know what the basic qualifications are, to become a cricket coach for a national team?

Comment: Trevor Bayliss, the current England head coach, used to be a real estate agent! It's definitely not necessary to have experience at the highest level of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to have experience in playing international matches to become a cricket coach, although that would help. I can list a number of national team coaches who never played at the highest level: [Tim Nielsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Nielsen)(coached the Australia national team), [Shane Jurgensen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane_Jurgensen)(current Bangladesh coach), [Richard Pybus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Pybus)(coached Pakistan) and probably most famously [John Buchanan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Buchanan_%28cricketer%29)(the Australian coach during their period of dominance in the late 90s to the early 2000s).

As for the coaching qualifications, each country seems to have its own coaching system. You can find out more about the different programs in some of the test countries at the links below:

1. India - http://cricketindiaacademy.com/cricket-coaches.aspx ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305060344/http://cricketindiaacademy.com/cricket-coaches.aspx))
2. Australia - http://www.cricket.com.au/get-involved/coaching ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140214151622/https://www.cricket.com.au/get-involved/coaching))
3. England - http://www.ecb.co.uk/development/coach-education/ ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160619060550/http://www.ecb.co.uk/development/coaching/coach-education))
4. South Africa - http://www.cricket.co.za/coaching.aspx?id=5 ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20141124153007/http://www.cricket.co.za/coaching.aspx?id=5))

Answer (score -2):

No prerequisite of playing international cricket matches. A former PAKISTANI coach **Richard** have no experience of international cricket ,but having very peachy, satisfactory and quality coaching. 
***REFERENCE:*** http://rootsbd.com/tag/richard-pybus-coaching

Qualification: must be enough education to communicate in **English** language to players easily.

https://sport360.com/article/cricket/uae-cricket/40237/going-out-get-your-level-2-cricket-coaching-qualification-icc-academy